# Displaying incomplete mutlipage entries in Freeform Pro {exp:freeform:entries}

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is it possible to show incomplete multipage entries within {exp:freeform:entries}?

Right now I have this:

```
{exp:freeform:entries form_id="2" status="open|pending|closed"}
...
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

It's only returning 'complete' entries.

The incomplete entries are being captured and are available in EE Admin.

Using FreeForm Pro 4.2.2 on EE 2.9.3

Answer (score 0):

I think the Solspace docs are outdated. It is not `status` but `default_status`. Try the following:

```
{exp:freeform:entries form_id="2" default_status="open|pending|closed"}
...
{/exp:freeform:entries}
```

That should get you what you want.

Comment: Hi tatlar - thanks for getting back.

I just tried:


`{exp:freeform:entries form_id="2" default_status="open|pending"}`

and it returned nothing at all – so not sure that one works?

Comment: Hmm. I am not sure what to tell you then. It works for all my freeform queries. Have you contacted Solspace support?